# Number of solutions using recursion

Tags: c, recursion

I've been trying to solve a problem using recursion:

The items at a store have the following costs:

- Ball: 1
- Hat:  5
- Jam: 20
- Crystal: 50

If you want to spend exactly 300 units on these items, find all combinations of purchases you can make.

This problem can be easily solved using for loops, but I wanted to do one better and use recursion instead, since all problems with iterative solutions also have corresponding recursive solutions.

My attempt at this was:

```
int recurse(int x, int y, int z, int w, int n)
{
 if(x > 300 || y > 60 || z > 15 || w > 6)
    return n;

 if(x + 5 * y + 20 * z + 50 * w == 300)
    return n + 1;

 recurse(x+1, y, z, w, n);
 recurse(x, y+1, z, w, n);
 recurse(x, y, z+1, w, n);
 recurse(x, y, z, w+1, n);
}

int main()
{

  int n;
  n = recurse(0,0,0,0,0);
  printf("Answer: %d", n);

  return 0;
}
```

Where `n` is the total number of solutions, `x` is the no. of balls, `y` is no. of hats, `z` is no. jams, and `w` is the no. of crystals

However when I run this code, it never ends.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162341/discussion-on-question-by-user129048-number-of-solutions-using-recursion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation is bad because you ignore the return value of your recursive call of `recurse`, easy to fix just return the addition of your return value:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int recurse(int x, int y, int z, int w, int n) {
  int value = x + 5 * y + 20 * z + 50 * w;
  if (value == 300) {
    return n + 1;
  } else if (value > 300) {
    return n;
  }

  return recurse(x + 1, y, z, w, n) + recurse(x, y + 1, z, w, n) +
         recurse(x, y, z + 1, w, n) + recurse(x, y, z, w + 1, n);
}

int main(void) {
  printf("Answer: %d", recurse(0, 0, 0, 0, 0));
}
```

But your implementation will take time... a lot of time... to compute the result.

> [Antti Haapala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/918959/antti-haapala) - well, I made the ending condition tighter, and then started testing. 62 took1.32 seconds, 64 2.3 seconds, 66 4.039 seconds to finish. The ratio was 1.75 for each 2 added. so minimally, those 300 will need 1.75 ^ ((300 - 66) / 2) * 4.039 seconds .. so that's in the whereabouts

Because you didn't turn your iterative implementation into a correct recursive function. Your function computes the number of *permutations* instead of number of *combinations*. In other words, in how many different orderings you can give the items and end up with 300.

---

Every iterative loop can be transform to tail-recursive function, C standard doesn't require that tail recursive function to be optimize by the compiler to avoid ***stackoverflow*** but most of compiler have this optimization.

This is hard to explain how to transform a function from iterative to recursive but as rule every for loop need the analogue function recursive. Like you see, I needed to create four function to achieve the same behavior.

Spoiler, this answer give code solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int magic(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
  return a + b * 5 + c * 20 + d * 50;
}

static int recur_d(int a, int b, int c, int d, int n, int max) {
  int ret = magic(a, b, c, d);
  if (ret >= max) {
    if (ret == max) {
      // printf("%d %d %d %d\n", a, b, c, d);
      return n + 1;
    }
    return n;
  }
  return recur_d(a, b, c, d + 1, n, max);
}

static int recur_c(int a, int b, int c, int n, int max) {
  if (magic(a, b, c, 0) > max) {
    return n;
  }
  return recur_c(a, b, c + 1, recur_d(a, b, c, 0, n, max), max);
}

static int recur_b(int a, int b, int n, int max) {
  if (magic(a, b, 0, 0) > max) {
    return n;
  }
  return recur_b(a, b + 1, recur_c(a, b, 0, n, max), max);
}

static int recur_a(int a, int n, int max) {
  if (magic(a, 0, 0, 0) > max) {
    return n;
  }
  return recur_a(a + 1, recur_b(a, 0, n, max), max);
}

static int iter(int max) {
  int n = 0;
  for (int a = 0; magic(a, 0, 0, 0) <= max; a++) {
    for (int b = 0; magic(a, b, 0, 0) <= max; b++) {
      for (int c = 0; magic(a, b, c, 0) <= max; c++) {
        for (int d = 0; magic(a, b, c, d) <= max; d++) {
          if (magic(a, b, c, d) == max) {
            // printf("%d %d %d %d\n", a, b, c, d);
            n++;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return n;
}

int main(void) { printf("%d %d\n", iter(300), recur_a(0, 0, 300)); }
```

Note: I commented the `printf()` to avoid long output.